# MySQL multiple insert: How to write a query to insert the new rows and ignore inserting duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I want to insert multiple rows in a MySQL table at once. One of the columns, column c, of that table is unique indexed. How to write a query to insert the new rows(rows where value of column c is not equal to the column c value of any previously inserted row) only and ignore inserting duplicate rows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use INSERT IGNORE instead of insert.Query will be like this .

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO person_tbl (last_name, first_name)
 VALUES( 'Jay', 'Thomas');
```

Comment: I tried doing that. But it also inserted duplicate columns. I guess the ignore stands for "Ignore unique key"

Comment: Beware that `IGNORE` will ignore *all* errors during the insertion—not just duplicate key errors.  It's often better to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (but then only set a column back to its incumbent value) instead, so that duplicate entries are ignored but other forms of error are still flagged.